# CSRF Protection for non form post requests

Tags: asp.net, csrf

Implementing CSRF tokens in hidden form fields is the standard protection for CSRF for form post requests.

However, how would you implement this for GET requests? Or ajax requests that POST json data instead of x-www-form-urlencoded for the request body? Are these types of things all handled on a case by case ad hoc basis?

Answer (score 2):

[OWASP says this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) about CSRF and GET requests:

> The ideal solution is to only include the CSRF token in POST requests
>   and modify server-side actions that have state changing affect to only
>   respond to POST requests. This is in fact what the RFC 2616 requires
>   for GET requests. If sensitive server-side actions are guaranteed to
>   only ever respond to POST requests, then there is no need to include
>   the token in GET requests.

Also, OWASP notes:

> Many implementations of this control include the challenge token in
>   GET (URL) requests  [...] **while this control does help mitigate the risk
>   of CSRF attacks, the unique per-session token is being exposed for GET
>   requests**. CSRF tokens in GET requests are potentially leaked at
>   several locations: browser history, HTTP log files, network appliances
>   that make a point to log the first line of an HTTP request, and
>   Referrer headers if the protected site links to an external site.

The trouble here is that if a user's token is leaked, you're still vulnerable - and it's all too easy to leak the token. I'm not sure that there's a good answer to your question that doesn't involve converting all of those GET requests to POST requests.

It's worth noting that the Viewstate feature in ASP.NET WebForms does offer some protection against CSRF, [though it's very limited](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Viewstate_.28ASP.NET.29) - in fact, it also only protects POSTback requests.

To state this more simply, you shouldn't use a GET request as an entry point to any function that does something beyond return a read only resource for a browser to render. So don't have an AJAX script make a GET based call to a URL like `transferMoney.aspx?fromAcct=xyz&toAcct=abc&amount=20`.

The HTTP specification [states explicitly](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) that HTTP GET requests should not have side effects. It's considered best practice to keep your GET requests [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) whenever possible.

I've written [an article](http://kylehodgson.com/2013/01/08/asp-netmvc-web-security-basics-csrf/) about protecting ASP.NET MVC against CSRF, it spells out a practical approach to applying the `AntiForgeryToken` to POST controller methods on your site.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the CSRF-protection pattern you're applying. First off, CSRF applies to endpoints that **change state**. If you're GET requests change state, then I advise that you modify them to POSTs. Having said that, it is a valid point.

The ideal place to persist Tokens is in the AUTH Header. This is the lowest common denominator across FORM-POSTs, AJAX and GET requests. You could of course store the Token in a Cookie, but there is a vulnerability in this design when applied to a multi-domain site.

You can parse the Token from a hidden field during FORM-POST without issue. Not much point in changing that. Assuming that your **GET** requests are invoked with AJAX, you can leverage JQuery's ***ajaxSetup*** method to automatically insert the Token on every AJAX request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "TOKEN " + myToken);
        }
    });
```

There is a relatively new pattern gaining traction called the Encrypted Token Pattern. It's described in detail [here](http://insidethecpu.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/encrypted-token-pattern/), and also on the official [OWASP CSRF Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Encrypted_Token_Pattern). There is also a working implementation called [ARMOR](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.Armor), which may offer you the flexbility you're looking for across various types of requests.